# Error: Module version mismatch - without removing node_modules

Tags: node.js

When trying to start up my application using `node app.js` I'm getting this error:

```
lucas@XYZ:~/app/lucas$ node app.js
module.js:583
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 57.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lucas/app/lucas/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
```

When I type in `node -v` I get `v6.5.0`

As [this website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) shows, this corresponds to version 48, so where the 57 is coming from?

I know the default solution is deleting node_modules but I'd like to understand what's going on here and try to avoid that, and any other similar approaches that involve reinstalling all modules etc. Question is more about understanding the actual problem.

EDIT: If you're curious whats in that `bindings.js` file this is all that's inside:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('../build/Release/canvas.node');
```

Comment: Could you show us the full traceback leading up to that?

Comment: @AKX added - see above

Answer (score 2):

Simply put Node 6.x is trying to open [a native module](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) built for Node 8.x.

Based on the traceback, it's the `canvas` module – you've somehow ended up with a newer native module for `canvas` in your `node_modules` than the Node you're running with. (One way this can happen is by using `nvm`, `n` or other node version manager.)

You don't necessarily have to nuke all of `node_modules` to fix this (though it doesn't hurt, and if you have a project that doesn't survive nuking `node_modules`, that's a problem in itself) – you could try renaming `node_modules/canvas` to `node_modules/canvas.backup` or something and running `npm install` (or `yarn install`) again (with the correct Node version active) and it should download/recompile the native module for `canvas` as it's reinstalling the now "missing" `canvas`.

Comment: Let's say on the same machine I create a new npm project, go inside, do a sanity check with `node -v` to confirm 6.5 (i know it's irrelevant to the folder its ran in) and then `npm install canvas` - the contents of node_module should be in line with my node version, no?

Comment: Yes, unless, say, an npm cache somewhere on your machine is broken and contains the wrong version of a native module or something.

Comment: that's exactly what I've done and it throws the same problem. How would I fix the cache issue? That wouldn't affect my existing node project, right?

Comment: It shouldn't. `npm cache clean`.